# How to know if zoom is currently running in sharing mode

Tags: windows, zoom-sdk

I want to programmatically stop and start zomm screen sharing (using means I know to manage).

The problem is : how to know if zoom is currently in sharing mode ?

Perhaps spying some process activities / launch ?

I've searched in AppData\Roaming\Zoom.

What I've noticed is an change of `zmonitorlog.bin` file in data subfolder each time I start/stop share. But it seems this file is crypted.

Is there registry key that I can spy ?

Comment: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/events#/paths/meeting.sharing_started/post

Comment: OK but I have to create a zoom app for that, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using:

```
handle = FindWindowA("ZPFloatToolbarClass",0)
```

Then with returned handle, check if this handle is visible. That means zoom is sharing the screen

```
IsWindowVisible(handle)
```